# How to make a custom dialog with checkbox list like setMultiChoiceItems, receive and send data?

Tags: java, android

I need to use a dialog like setMultiChoiceItems style but with more information, so I'm using a custom layout.

My layout contains one image field, another title field, another description field, and another one from a checkbox.

[image]

I already managed to make it work like this:

[image]

I know I need to use a setAdapter instead of setMultiChoiceItems. So far so good.

My problem is how I can open the dialog with some options already selected? And later to receive all selected items to send to the server?

With setMultiChoiceItems I can make it work like this:

[image]

But I can not seem to work with the custom layout.

Here is my code:

**##### ArrayList - ALItensValues #####**

```
public class ALItensValues {
    private int icon;
    private String value;
    private String titulo;
    private String descricao;

    public ALItensValues(int icon, String value, String titulo, String descricao) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.value = value;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    int getIcon() { return icon; }
    String getValue() { return value; }
    String getTitulo() { return titulo; }
    String getDescricao() { return descricao; }
}
```

**##### Adapter - ALItensValuesAdapter #####**

```
private class ALItensValuesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ALItensValues> mData;
    private Context mContext;

    ALItensValuesAdapter(ArrayList<ALItensValues> aldata, Context context) {
        this.mData = aldata;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = Objects.requireNonNull(mInflater).inflate(R.layout.multipleselectcustom_lines, null);
        }

        ImageView icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgvicon);
        icon.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getIcon());
        TextView titulo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_titulo);
        titulo.setText(mData.get(position).getTitulo());
        TextView decricao = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_desc);
        decricao.setText(mData.get(position).getDescricao());
        CheckBox checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            checkbox.toggle();
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**#### Layout Itens - R.layout.multipleselectcustom_lines ####**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvicon"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
                android:text="Titulo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtv_titulo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Descrição"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtv_desc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/chkbox"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**#### Activity Class ####**

```
public class FormsMultipleSelectCustomJava extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multipleselectcustom);

// I get the items that should be selected separated by commas.
// And I do the following to transform into array, 
//  but I do not know how to use it in dialog.:

String selectItensServer = "0b2,0e5,0f6,0h8";  
String[] selectInitItens = selectItensServer.split(",");

// List of items that should appear in the dialog.

        ArrayList<ALItensValues> AlertDialogitemList = new ArrayList<>();
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_bicycle, "0a1", "Test 1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_btc, "0b2", "Test 2", "Duis at ullamcorper quam"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_car, "0c3", "Test 3", "Aenean aliquam sit amet nibh eget bibendum"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_credit_card, "0d4", "Test 4", "Sed a est vel velit rutrum porta"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_gamepad, "0e5", "Test 5", "Phasellus pellentesque arcu et fermentum tempus"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_gift, "0f6", "Test 6", "Integer arcu leo, consequat eget tempus sed"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_paypal, "0g7", "Test 7", "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_taxi, "0h8", "Test 8", "Proin iaculis, velit ac consectetur bibendum, orci nisi scelerisque"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_utensils, "0i9", "Test 9", "Ut ullamcorper nisi dui, et sagittis ante mollis vitae"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_whatsapp, "k10", "Test 10", "Donec rhoncus magna in mauris ultricies"));


// Button that opens the dialog.
        Button btnopendialog = findViewById(R.id.btnopendialog);
        btnopendialog.setOnClickListener(v -> {
AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuider = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialogbuider.setCancelable(false);
    dialogbuider.setTitle("Itens");
    ALItensValuesAdapter mAdapter = new ALItensValuesAdapter(ALitensvalues, context);
    dialogbuider.setAdapter(mAdapter, (dialog, which) -> {
        // I do not know what to do here. 
        // But I think it should be here that I start the selected items.
    });
    dialogbuider.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, which) -> {
        // And once selected, I would like to display in textview the items that are currently selected.
    });
    dialogbuider.setNeutralButton("Clear", (dialogInterface, which) -> { 
        // Here should clear all checkboxes
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = dialogbuider.create();
    ListView listView = dialog.getListView();
    listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY)); 
    listView.setDividerHeight(2);
    dialog.show();
        });

//Button to send to server.
        findViewById(R.id.btnsend).setOnClickListener(v -> {
             //I need to know how to retrieve the selected items.
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Le Thanh Tan, Interfaces are the way to go.

1. Create MyInterface.java file and add this piece of code

   ```
   public interface MyInterface {
       void onItemChecked(int position);
   }
   ```
2. Update your ALItensValues class as following

   ```
   public class ALItensValues {
     private int icon;
     private String value;
     private String titulo;
     private String descricao;
     private Boolean isChecked;

     public ALItensValues(int icon, String value, String titulo, String descricao, Boolean isChecked) {
      this.icon = icon;
      this.value = value;
      this.titulo = titulo;
      this.descricao = descricao;
      this.isChecked = isChecked;
     }

     int getIcon() { return icon; }
     String getValue() { return value; }
     String getTitulo() { return titulo; }
     String getDescricao() { return descricao; }
     Boolean getChecked() { return isChecked; }
     void setChecked(Boolean isChecked) {
       this.isChecked = isChecked;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Now your Activity will be

   ```
   public class FormsMultipleSelectCustomJava extends AppCompatActivity {

      String selectItensServer;  
      String[] selectInitItens;
      ArrayList<ALItensValues> AlertDialogitemList = new ArrayList<>();
      ArrayList<ALItensValues> selectedItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_multipleselectcustom);

           selectItensServer = "0b2,0e5,0f6,0h8";  
           selectInitItens = selectItensServer.split(",");

           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_bicycle, "0a1", "Test 1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", true));
           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_btc, "0b2", "Test 2", "Duis at ullamcorper quam", true));
           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_car, "0c3", "Test 3", "Aenean aliquam sit amet nibh eget bibendum", false));
           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_credit_card, "0d4", "Test 4", "Sed a est vel velit rutrum porta", true));
           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_gamepad, "0e5", "Test 5", "Phasellus pellentesque arcu et fermentum tempus", false));
           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_gift, "0f6", "Test 6", "Integer arcu leo, consequat eget tempus sed", true));
           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_paypal, "0g7", "Test 7", "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus", false));
           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_taxi, "0h8", "Test 8", "Proin iaculis, velit ac consectetur bibendum, orci nisi scelerisque", true));
           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_utensils, "0i9", "Test 9", "Ut ullamcorper nisi dui, et sagittis ante mollis vitae", false));
           AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValues(R.drawable.atrib_whatsapp, "k10", "Test 10", "Donec rhoncus magna in mauris ultricies", true));

         Button btnopendialog = findViewById(R.id.btnopendialog);
         btnopendialog.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuider = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialogbuider.setCancelable(false);
                dialogbuider.setTitle("Itens");
                ALItensValuesAdapter mAdapter = new ALItensValuesAdapter(ALitensvalues, context, new MyInterface() {
                  @Override
                  public void onItemChecked(int position) 
                    {
               AlertDialogitemList.get(position).setChecked(!AlertDialogitemList.get(position).getChecked())
                    }
                 });
               dialogbuider.setAdapter(mAdapter, (dialog, which) -> {

               });
               dialogbuider.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, which) -> {

               });
               dialogbuider.setNeutralButton("Clear", (dialogInterface, which) -> { 
               });
               AlertDialog dialog = dialogbuider.create();
               ListView listView = dialog.getListView();
               listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY)); 
               listView.setDividerHeight(2);
               dialog.show();
          });


            findViewById(R.id.btnsend).setOnClickListener(v -> {
                for(ALItensValues item : AlertDialogitemList) {
                     if(item.isChecked()) {
                          selectedItemsList.add(item);
                     }
                }
               // selected items can be sent to server
         });
      }
   }
   ```
4. Your Adapter

   ```
   private class ALItensValuesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      private ArrayList<ALItensValues> mData;
      private Context mContext;
      private MyInterface interface;

      ALItensValuesAdapter(ArrayList<ALItensValues> aldata, Context context, MyInterface interface) {
         this.mData = aldata;
         this.mContext = context;
         this.interface = interface;
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
         return mData.size();
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int position) {
         return null;
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
          return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           if (convertView == null) {
              LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              convertView = Objects.requireNonNull(mInflater).inflate(R.layout.multipleselectcustom_lines, null);
           }

           ImageView icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgvicon);
           icon.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getIcon());
           TextView titulo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_titulo);
           titulo.setText(mData.get(position).getTitulo());
           TextView decricao = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_desc);
           decricao.setText(mData.get(position).getDescricao());
           CheckBox checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
           if(mData.get(position).getChecked()) {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
           } else {
                checkbox.setChecked(false);
           }
           convertView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
               this.interface.onItemChecked(position);
               checkbox.toggle();
           });
      return convertView;
     }
   }
   ```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It still did not work out for me. The dialog is not returning anything when I send it. And when I open the dialog again the items that have been modified do not appear. I think I might be doing something wrong. I will try to recreate again and study every step of your code to try to make it work.

Comment: Cool. Try it out and get back to me if something is not working.

Comment: I have refitted everything and I still have problems. In your mode the checked items are linked to the ArrayList. This makes it difficult for me to start the checked items because I can not do this in the constructor. The Arraylist items are fixed, and there would not be a table to loop to start the checked items. And so I also can not use the button to clean everything.Ideally, checked items should be done in a position-separated list just like setMultiChoiceItems

Comment: After so much breaking my head I got do it your way, and I corrected some mistakes.I've selected your question as correct, and I'll ask another question the full way to see if anyone can figure out a way to simplify the code. 
Thank you  ♥

Comment: In this other question you can see the complete code that I made according to your help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177848/how-can-i-simplify-my-dialog-code-with-list-and-checkboxes-in-custom-layout

Comment: Happy to know my mistakes. Can you please let me know.

Comment: It was just a few minor adjustments. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsx4s.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqZvR.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB2hN.png 
And a few other things I did to work the way I wanted to.  You can see all the adjusts in this other question.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177848/how-can-i-simplify-my-dialog-code-with-list-and-checkboxes-in-custom-layout Thanks for your help.

Comment: As you have asked "My problem is how I can open the dialog with some options already selected?" To solve this problem I was not setting default value for isChecked. So some of the items are already checked if you need them to be. May be those are the issues while I was copy pasting it from android studio.

Comment: Any ways thanks for letting me know. I am updating the answer as well.

Comment: Yes I understood, but the items are dynamic, and by the constructor I would have to put the fixed values ​​manually. Thank you so much, anyway you helped me a lot.

Comment: I saw your change. But the "MyInterface interface" line of error in android studio. The word interface conflicts. Ideally, add a letter: "MyInterface mInterface",

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this.

add a `HashSet` to save checked item in your Adapter class, and add some method to get/set checked items, like this:

```
private class ALItensValuesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ... other code

    // save checked items
    private HashSet<ALItensValues> mCheckedSet = new HashSet<ALItensValues>();

    public HashSet<ALItensValues> getCheckedSet(){
        return mCheckedSet;
    }

    public void setCheckedSet(HashSet<ALItensValues> set){
        this.mCheckedSet = set;
        notifyDatasetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ... other code

        // delete code
        // convertView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //    checkbox.toggle();
        // });
        // add code
        final ALItensValues item = mData.get(position);
        // set check state by mCheckedSet
        checkbox.setCheck(mCheckedSet.contains(item));
        convertView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mCheckSet.contains(item)){
                mCheckSet.remove(item);
            } else {
                mCheckSet.add(item);
            }
            notifyDatasetChanged();
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

then you can use `setCheckedSet`/`getCheckedSet` to set or get checked items.

in your activity class

```
dialogbuider.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, which) -> {
    // get the check items when click 'OK' button
    HashSet<ALItensValues> checkedSet = mAdapter.getCheckedSet();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, it still did not work for me. Or I still do not know how to use. I'll try to best study your code.

Comment: @ Samanta Silva: I edited my reply to explain how to use, hope help you.

Comment: Thanks. That part of the SetPositiveButton is all ok. But the problem is about the initial items ("0b2,0e5,0f6,0h8"), so I understood of your way I would have to create a list with these items, and the server will only send the value of the items. And the dialog does not keep the selected items when I reopen. I'm a bit confused to explain. I'm going to do some more tests and if it does not work out then I'll explain what's going on better.