# How can I simplify my Dialog code with List and Checkboxes in Custom Layout?

Tags: java, android

I need to use a dialog like setMultiChoiceItems style but with more information, so I'm using a custom layout.

I think my code got really big and messy. And I wonder if there is any other simpler way to do this.

**#### The dialog in operation: ####**

[image]

**#### Activity Layout: R.layout.activity_formsmultipleselectcustom_java ####**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FormsMultipleSelectCustomJava">

    <Button
            android:text="Dialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btndialog" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnenviar"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnenviar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btndialog" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**#### Itens Layout: R.layout.activity_formsmultipleselectcustom_java_lines ####**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvicon"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
                android:text="Titulo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtv_titulo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Descrição"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtv_desc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/chkbox"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**#### ALItensValuesList ####**

```
public class ALItensValuesList {
    private int icon;
    private String value;
    private String titulo;
    private String descricao;
    private Boolean isChecked;

    public ALItensValuesList (int icon, String value, String titulo, String descricao) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.value = value;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.isChecked = false;
    }

    int getIcon() { return icon; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public String getTitulo() { return titulo; }
    String getDescricao() { return descricao; }
    public Boolean getChecked() { return isChecked; }
    public void setChecked(Boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
}
```

**#### ALItensInterface (Interface for ItemChecked in Adapter) ####**

```
public interface ALItensInterface {
    void onItemChecked(int position);
}
```

**#### ALItensValuesAdapter ####**

```
public class ALItensValuesAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<ALItensValuesList> mData;
    private Context mContext;
    private ALItensInterface minterface;

    public ALItensValuesAdapter(ArrayList<ALItensValuesList> aldata, Context context, ALItensInterface minterface) {
        this.mData = aldata;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.minterface = minterface;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = Objects.requireNonNull(mInflater).inflate(R.layout.activity_formsmultipleselectcustom_java_lines, null);
        }

        ImageView icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgvicon);
        icon.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getIcon());
        TextView titulo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_titulo);
        titulo.setText(mData.get(position).getTitulo());
        TextView decricao = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_desc);
        decricao.setText(mData.get(position).getDescricao());
        CheckBox checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
        checkbox.setChecked(mData.get(position).getChecked());

        // When you click on the item line.
        convertView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            checkbox.toggle();
            this.minterface.onItemChecked(position);
        });

        // When you click directly on the checkbox
        checkbox.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            this.minterface.onItemChecked(position);
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**#### Activity of Dialog ####**

```
public class FormsMultipleSelectCustomJava extends AppCompatActivity {

    String selectItensServer;
    String[] selectInitItens;
    ArrayList<String> selectedItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_formsmultipleselectcustom_java);

        selectItensServer = "0b2,0e5,0f6,0h8"; // Example of random value received by the server.
        selectInitItens = selectItensServer.split(",");

        // Fixed values ​​that fill the dialog
        ArrayList<ALItensValuesList> AlertDialogitemList = new ArrayList<>();
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_bicycle, "0a1", "Test 1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_btc, "0b2", "Test 2", "Duis at ullamcorper quam"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_car, "0c3", "Test 3", "Aenean aliquam sit amet nibh eget bibendum"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_credit_card, "0d4", "Test 4", "Sed a est vel velit rutrum porta"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_gamepad, "0e5", "Test 5", "Phasellus pellentesque arcu et fermentum tempus"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_gift, "0f6", "Test 6", "Integer arcu leo, consequat eget tempus sed"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_paypal, "0g7", "Test 7", "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_taxi, "0h8", "Test 8", "Proin iaculis, velit ac consectetur bibendum, orci nisi scelerisque"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_utensils, "0i9", "Test 9", "Ut ullamcorper nisi dui, et sagittis ante mollis vitae"));
        AlertDialogitemList.add(new ALItensValuesList(R.drawable.atrib_whatsapp, "k10", "Test 10", "Donec rhoncus magna in mauris ultricies"));

        // Starting with some values ​​already selected. 
        // I would like to know a way to simplify this loop.
        StringBuilder itensexib = new StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < AlertDialogitemList.size(); i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < selectInitItens.length; j++) {
                 if (AlertDialogitemList.get(i).getValue().equals(selectInitItens[j])) {
                     AlertDialogitemList.get(i).setChecked(true);
                     selectedItemsList.add(AlertDialogitemList.get(i).getValue());
                     itensexib.append(AlertDialogitemList.get(i).getTitulo()+",");
                 }
             }
         }

        // Displays the items selected on the button.
        Button btnopendialog = findViewById(R.id.btndialog);
         if(selectedItemsList.size() >= 1) {
             btnopendialog.setText(itensexib);
         } else {
             btnopendialog.setText("Select Itens");
         }

        // Creating the dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuider = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogbuider.setCancelable(false);
        dialogbuider.setTitle("Itens");
        ALItensValuesAdapter mAdapter = new ALItensValuesAdapter(AlertDialogitemList, this, new ALItensInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onItemChecked(int position)
            {
                AlertDialogitemList.get(position).setChecked(!AlertDialogitemList.get(position).getChecked());
            }
        });
        dialogbuider.setAdapter(mAdapter, (dialog, which) -> {});

        dialogbuider.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, which) -> {
            StringBuilder itensexib2 = new StringBuilder();
            selectedItemsList.clear();
            for(ALItensValuesList item : AlertDialogitemList) {
                if(item.getChecked()) {
                    selectedItemsList.add(item.getValue());
                    itensexib2.append(item.getTitulo()+",");
                }
            }
            if(selectedItemsList.size() > 0) {
                btnopendialog.setText(itensexib2);
            } else {
                btnopendialog.setText("Select Itens");
            }
        });

        dialogbuider.setNeutralButton("Clear", (dialogInterface, which) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < AlertDialogitemList.size(); i++){
                AlertDialogitemList.get(i).setChecked(false);
            }
            selectedItemsList.clear();
            btnopendialog.setText("Select Itens");
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = dialogbuider.create();
        ListView listView = dialog.getListView();
        listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));
        listView.setDividerHeight(2);
        btnopendialog.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dialog.show();
        });

        // Displays the values ​​that will be sent by the form.
        findViewById(R.id.btnenviar).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, selectedItemsList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });
}
```

If anyone knows other ways to make this dialog work this way, I'd love to meet.

Comment: You can use DialogFragment so the whole dialog related code shifted from activity to DialogFragment.

Comment: @pateldhavalr I've never used DialogFragment, would it make my code smaller and simpler? Could you give me an example of using lists with checkboxes in DialogFragment? I think it's easy to find in Google how to work with DialogFragment, but I already researched a lot about lists with checkboxes and I can not find anything I can use with a custom layout. I've been trying to do this for two weeks.

Comment: Hi ,There are many library for your requirement but .In many case these library can't work as our requrement.So,  I think your are doing is the best.

Comment: @RahulKushwaha Thanks. I have not really found any library that does what I'm looking for. But I still think my code can be simplified, I'm studying a method for this.

Comment: Your Code is best.I have used this code in my project.

Comment: @RahulKushwaha Thanks. I'm glad to know that my code is useful to you. ♥

Answer (score 0):

Your Logic code remains same. but it shifted into Dialog Fragment so less code in activity and all dialog related code shifted in dialog fragment.

Here Simple DialogFragment Code you can see.

```
public class SimpleDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public static final String TAG = "SimpleDialogFragment";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
    @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_company_insight, container);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setCancelable(false);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.AppTheme_FullWidthDialog_MoreRounded);
}

}
```

For opening Dialog from Fragment :

```
new SimpleDialogFragment ()
        .show(getChildFragmentManager(), SimpleDialogFragment .TAG);
```

For opening dialog from activity :

```
  new SimpleDialogFragment ()
        .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), SimpleDialogFragment .TAG);
```

You can code here like simple fragment. if still any query comment here , i will see.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's still very confusing for me. I can not figure out how to make this work with lists and checkboxes or how to transfer my code to this DialogFragment model. I think it will take me a few days to figure it all out. Thank you anyway.